# Decompress a .rar file using ZipFile in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, zip

I have an application of upload directories: when I upload a directory it must be `.zip` et `.rar` . when I decompress a `.zip` file there is no problem but in the case of `.rar` I have an exception here:

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
zf = new ZipFile(fs);
```

I have this exception :

> Cannot find central directory.

What is the reason of this exception? How can i fix this code?

Comment: Maybe a trick question, but ZipFile suggests that it can only use ZIP files, and not RAR files.

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? Rar files use a completely different compression algorithm than zip files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737/net-library-to-unzip-zip-and-rar-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.rar is a different compression format then .zip

You could use http://www.chilkatsoft.com/rar-dotnet.asp instead.

Sample: http://www.example-code.com/csharp/rar_list.asp

Comment: i did like this : ` Chilkat.Rar obj = new Chilkat.Rar();
                       bool success = obj.Open(fs.Name);
                       bool opera = obj.Unrar(Path.Combine(@"D:\DataDownloadCenter", path2));
` the two booleans are true as a value but no decompression

Comment: Have you checked that your .rar actually contains any content?